# PHP include leaving invisible character footprint

Tags: php, json, include, echo

I am setting up a game server on my dedicated server using PHP and I have run into this problem. I have a script that I run to get the game state as JSON.

To save bandwidth and processing time, I decided that on the update script, I want to directly run this same script after I update the server, so I just include it:

```
include "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/game/get/get_session_info.php";
```

This does work, but the problem is that this include statement inserts a single invisible character before the output of that script that makes it impossible to parse as JSON.

I know it is from the include, because for every include I put in the script, one of these invisible characters is inserted.

If I run that script directly from its URL, the length is 8014; if I run it from my update script, the length is 8015.

How can I prevent PHP from inserting that extra character, or run the script and return its results differently so that this does not happen?

---

#### Note:

- The update script does not echo **anything**
- The only echo in `get_session_info.php` is `echo trim(json_encode($game));`

---

Here is the start of the string from the update script:

> {"state":2,"players":4,"loc1":"15,25,35",

And in HEX:

> **feff**7b227374617465223a322c22706c6179657273223a342c226c6f6331223a2231352c32352c3335222c

And the same string from `get_session_info.php`:

> {"state":2,"players":4,"loc1":"15,25,35",

And in HEX:

> 7b227374617465223a322c22706c6179657273223a342c226c6f6331223a2231352c32352c3335222c

It appears to be inserting `feff` for each include (except the one that includes my mysqli_connect, actually...).

Comment: Is your "invisible character" always at the start ?

Comment: Why then not just do: `substr($yourInput, 1)` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Well I could do that, but there are some cases when I need to include multiple files, and then that number of characters is variable. They shouldn't be there in the first place. This could be solved with a for-loop, but it's not as clean as preventing it in the first place.

Comment: Well then you have to give us more information and show us more code. How the start from the output looks like, maybe which hex code it has, so we know with which character we deal with and that with the code we maybe can spot from where it comes

Comment: Have you checked that all the `php` files used in the chain have no white space before any `<?php` tags?

Comment: @Rizier123 I have updated the question with the strings and HEX values.

Comment: @diggersworld I don't see any white-space before or after the <?php and ?> in either file.

Comment: @MathNerdProductions Did you opened the files with a hex editor and looked that you don't have anything in front? Because `FEFF` is a [`ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm)

Comment: did you save the file as utf8 with BOM? i think this is the case, just remove the BOM (byte-order mask)

Comment: @Rizier123 brilliant. There were 3 hex characters ahead of the <?php that I could not see. I just created this as a .php file from Notepad...I guess Notepad inserted that character.

Comment: @NikosM. I just saved it as a UTF-8 file in Notepad. I don't see any option for BOM or non-BOM.

Comment: notepad++ has an option to save as utf8 without BOM

Comment: @NikosM. I'll have to download that then.

Comment: @MathNerdProductions Just  in the menu under encoding, there you should see UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the include that generates the invisible character, but most probably the file you are including. Check for whitespaces outside PHP scope in that file.